# How to declare onclick function in HTML property in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

First time asking question here.

Can someone help me in declaring dynamic **onclick** function in HTML property inside **forEach** function using **TypeScript**?

By the way, i am new in typescript. hehe.

Here is my old code that i want to convert in TypeScript:

```
const MyClass = (() =>
{
    let this_MyClass = {};

    this_MyClass.load = () =>
    {
        let tr;
        $.each(data, function()
        {
            tr += 
                `<tr>
                    <td><button onclick = "MyClass.set_id(${this.id})">Edit</button></td> 
                </tr>`;
         }
         $("#table_id tbody").html(tr);
    };

    this_MyClass.set_id = (id) =>
    {
        //my codes here
    };

    return this_MyClass;

})();
```

---

My new code in typescript(but its not working):

```
class MyClass
{

    load()
    {
        let tr:any;
        let iteration = 0;

        data.forEach((value:{id: number;}) =>
        {
            tr +=
               `<tr>
                   <td><button id="btn_edit${iteration}">Edit</button></td>
               </tr>`;

        document.getElementById(`btn_edit${iteration}`)?.addEventListener("click", 
            (e: Event) => this.set_id(value.id));

            iteration++;
        });
        $("#table_id tbody").html(tr);
    }

    set_id(id:number)
    {
        //my codes here
    }
}
```

---

can someone help me.

> Code Update: location of "**set_id**" method

Comment: is the html is added to the dom ?

Comment: no sir. HTML is already defined.

Comment: then why are you adding this $("#table_id tbody").html(tr);, which means you are adding to the dom isn't, i was asking does the dynamic tr gets added and click functionality is not working or tr itself is not getting added

Comment: aaah... yes it is added to the DOM. sorry.,

Comment: exactly. the click functionality is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the TS code you are adding event listener on the element which is not present in the DOM yet. First add the element into the `DOM` and then add event listener.

**Working code:**

```
class MyClass {
    load() {
       // let data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] Adding for testing
        let tr: any;
        let iteration = 0;
        let trBtnIds = [];
        data.forEach((value: { id: number }) => {
            tr +=
                `<tr>
                   <td><button  id="btn_edit${iteration}">Edit</button></td>
               </tr>`;
            trBtnIds.push({
                iteration,
                value
            });
            iteration++;
        });
        $("#table_id tbody").html(tr);

        trBtnIds.forEach(item => {
            document.getElementById(`btn_edit${item.iteration}`) ?.addEventListener("click", (e: Event) => {
                this.set_id(item.value.id);
            });
        });

    }
    set_id(id: number) {
        console.log(id);
    }
}

/* Adding these line for testing */
//let myClassObject = new MyClass();
//myClassObject.load();
```

**Babel compiled working code**

```js
"use strict";
function _instanceof(left, right) { if (right != null && typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && right[Symbol.hasInstance]) { return !!right[Symbol.hasInstance](left); } else { return left instanceof right; } }
function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!_instanceof(instance, Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }
function _defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } }
function _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }
var MyClass =
/*#__PURE__*/
function () {
  function MyClass() {
    _classCallCheck(this, MyClass);
  }
  _createClass(MyClass, [{
    key: "load",
    value: function load() {
      var _this = this;
      var data = [{
        id: 1
      }, {
        id: 2
      }, {
        id: 3
      }]; //Adding for testing
      var tr;
      var iteration = 0;
      var trBtnIds = [];
      data.forEach(function (value) {
        tr += "<tr>\n                   <td><button  id=\"btn_edit".concat(iteration, "\">Edit</button></td>\n               </tr>");
        trBtnIds.push({
          iteration: iteration,
          value: value
        });
        iteration++;
      });
      $("#table_id tbody").html(tr);
      trBtnIds.forEach(function (item) {
        var _document$getElementB;
        (_document$getElementB = document.getElementById("btn_edit".concat(item.iteration))) === null || _document$getElementB === void 0 ? void 0 : _document$getElementB.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          _this.set_id(item.value.id);
        });
      });
    }
  }, {
    key: "set_id",
    value: function set_id(id) {
      console.log(id);
    }
  }]);
  return MyClass;
}();
/* Adding these line for testing */

var myClassObject = new MyClass();
myClassObject.load();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id">
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Alternate approach:**

Instead of creating event listener for each `td button`. Use javascript event bubbling technique. 
Listening to event for all `td buttons` is expensive.

Here is the example.

Create the event listener on the table or the wrapping element.

**HTML**

```
<table id="table_id">
</table>
```

**Script**

```
class MyClass {
    load() {
       // let data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] /**Adding for testing */
        let tr: any;
        let iteration = 0;
        let trBtnIds = [];
        data.forEach((value: { id: number }) => {
            tr +=
                `<tr>
                   <td><button data-id="${value.id}" id="btn_edit${iteration}">Edit</button></td>
               </tr>`;
            trBtnIds.push({
                iteration,
                value
            });
            iteration++;
        });
        $("#table_id tbody").html(tr);

        let ele = document.getElementById('table_id');
        ele.addEventListener('click', event => {
            console.log(event.target);
            let target = event.target;
            if (target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && target.dataset && target.dataset.id) {
                let id = target.dataset.id;
                this.set_id(id);
            }
        });

    }
    set_id(id: number) {
        console.log(id);
    }
}

/**Adding for testing */
//let myClassObject = new MyClass();
//myClassObject.load();
```

**Babel compiled working code**

```js
"use strict ";

        function _instanceof(left, right) {
            if (right != null && typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && right[Symbol.hasInstance]) {
                return !!right[Symbol.hasInstance](left);
            } else {
                return left instanceof right;
            }
        }

        function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
            if (!_instanceof(instance, Constructor)) {
                throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
            }
        }

        function _defineProperties(target, props) {
            for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
                var descriptor = props[i];
                descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
                descriptor.configurable = true;
                if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
                Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
            }
        }

        function _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
            if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
            if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
            return Constructor;
        }
        var MyClass =
            /*#__PURE__*/
            function() {
                function MyClass() {
                    _classCallCheck(this, MyClass);
                }
                _createClass(MyClass, [{
                    key: "load",
                    value: function load() {
                        var _this = this;
                        var data = [{
                            id: 1
                        }, {
                            id: 2
                        }, {
                            id: 3
                        }];
                        /**Adding for testing */
                        var tr;
                        var iteration = 0;
                        var trBtnIds = [];
                        data.forEach(function(value) {
                            tr += "<tr>\n                   <td><button data-id=\"".concat(value.id, "\" id=\"btn_edit").concat(iteration, "\">Edit</button></td>\n               </tr>");
                            trBtnIds.push({
                                iteration: iteration,
                                value: value
                            });
                            iteration++;
                        });
                        $("#table_id tbody").html(tr);
                        var ele = document.getElementById('table_id');
                        ele.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                            var target = event.target;
                            if (_instanceof(target, HTMLButtonElement) && target.dataset && target.dataset.id) {
                                var id = target.dataset.id;
                                _this.set_id(id);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, {
                    key: "set_id",
                    value: function set_id(id) {
                        console.log("ID:", id);
                    }
                }]);
                return MyClass;
            }();
        /**Adding for testing */

        var myClassObject = new MyClass();
        myClassObject.load();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="table_id">
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Add the description what was going wrong so it will be helpful to understand the problem !!

Comment: i got an error 
`Uncaught TypeError: this.set_id is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (model:1)`

Comment: i got an error `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.`  `TS2339: Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. `

Comment: I have updated the code, Please change the code inside `addEventListner` and run it and check the console what is printed in console.

Comment: I have added one more check, run again and can you check the console what you see in console. 

Now you should not get this error `TS2339: Property 'dataset' does not exist on type`

Comment: Hi @Sohail thank you for your response. I editted my codes in question section. please take a look at it once more. Again, thank you.

Comment: Add your event listener code after this line ‘$(“#table_id tbody”).html(tr);.

Comment: @Sohail Thank you for your help. i just got problem with "this" keyword to get my "set_id" method, because my load function is inside the success method of ajax. but i already fix it. Again thank you for your help!